# How to explicitly broadcast a tensor to match another's shape in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have three tensors, `A, B and C` in tensorflow, `A` and `B` are both of shape `(m, n, r)`, `C` is a binary tensor of shape `(m, n, 1)`.

I want to select elements from either A or B based on the value of `C`. The obvious tool is `tf.select`, however that does not have broadcasting semantics, so I need to first explicitly broadcast `C` to the same shape as A and B.

This would be my first attempt at how to do this, but it doesn't like me mixing a tensor (`tf.shape(A)[2]`) into the shape list.

```
import tensorflow as tf
A = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
B = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
C = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 1])
C = tf.greater_equal(C, tf.zeros_like(C))

C = tf.tile(C, [1,1,tf.shape(A)[2]])
D = tf.select(C, A, B)
```

What's the correct approach here?

Comment: One hack that works: I can use the broadcasting semantics of *multiply* and multiply by a ones tensor thus: `Expander = tf.ones_like(B)`, then
`C = Expander*C`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:** In all versions of TensorFlow since 0.12rc0, the code in the question works directly. TensorFlow will automatically stack tensors and Python numbers into a tensor argument. The solution below using `tf.pack()` is only needed in versions prior to 0.12rc0. Note that `tf.pack()` was renamed to [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) in TensorFlow 1.0.

---

Your solution is very close to working. You should replace the line:

```
C = tf.tile(C, [1,1,tf.shape(C)[2]])
```

...with the following:

```
C = tf.tile(C, tf.pack([1, 1, tf.shape(A)[2]]))
```

(The reason for the issue is that TensorFlow won't implicitly convert a list of tensors and Python literals into a tensor. [`tf.pack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) takes a list of tensors, so it will convert each of the elements in its input (`1`, `1`, and `tf.shape(C)[2]`) to a tensor. Since each element is a scalar, the result will be a vector.)

Comment: I think you have an extra `[` and are missing a `)`, but then I get a somewhat cryptic error when I *run* the tf session: `InvalidArgumentError: Inputs to operation Select_13 of type Select must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: dim { size: 20 } dim { size: 100 } dim { size: 1 } != input 1: dim { size: 20 } dim { size: 100 } dim { size: 10 }`

Comment: Good point, and I updated the answer - also, the argument to `tf.shape()` should have been `A` (or `B`). This works for me - what error are you seeing?

Comment: Yeah it's fixed now :) didn't notice the incorrect parameter to `tf.shape()`. Thanks!

Comment: This is `tf.stack` now, yes?

Comment: Yes, but there is no longer any need to use `tf.stack()` to solve this problem (see edit). The fix to the underlying issue came long before the rename of `tf.pack()` to `tf.stack()`, so I'm going to keep it as `tf.pack()` for historical accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a dirty hack:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def broadcast(tensor, shape):
    return tensor + tf.zeros(shape, dtype=tensor.dtype)

A = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
B = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
C = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 1])

C = broadcast(C, A.shape)
D = tf.select(C, A, B)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the newest tensorflow version(2.0), you can use `tf.broadcast_to` as below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
B = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
C = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 1])
C = tf.greater_equal(C, tf.zeros_like(C))
C = tf.broadcast_to(C, A.shape)

D = tf.where(C,A,B)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

def broadcast(tensor, shape):
     """Broadcasts ``x`` to have shape ``shape``.
                                                                   |
     Uses ``tf.Assert`` statements to ensure that the broadcast is
     valid.

     First calculates the number of missing dimensions in 
     ``tf.shape(x)`` and left-pads the shape of ``x`` with that many 
     ones. Then identifies the dimensions of ``x`` that require
     tiling and tiles those dimensions appropriately.

     Args:
         x (tf.Tensor): The tensor to broadcast.
         shape (Union[tf.TensorShape, tf.Tensor, Sequence[int]]): 
             The shape to broadcast to.

     Returns:
         tf.Tensor: ``x``, reshaped and tiled to have shape ``shape``.

     """
     with tf.name_scope('broadcast') as scope:
         shape_x = tf.shape(x)
         rank_x = tf.shape(shape0)[0]
         shape_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(shape, preferred_dtype=tf.int32)
         rank_t = tf.shape(shape1)[0]

         with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Assert(
             rank_t >= rank_x,
             ['len(shape) must be >= tf.rank(x)', shape_x, shape_t],
             summarize=255
         )]):
             missing_dims = tf.ones(tf.stack([rank_t - rank_x], 0), tf.int32)

         shape_x_ = tf.concat([missing_dims, shape_x], 0)
         should_tile = tf.equal(shape_x_, 1)

         with tf.control_dependencies([tf.Assert(
             tf.reduce_all(tf.logical_or(tf.equal(shape_x_, shape_t), should_tile),
             ['cannot broadcast shapes', shape_x, shape_t],
             summarize=255
         )]):
             multiples = tf.where(should_tile, shape_t, tf.ones_like(shape_t))
             out = tf.tile(tf.reshape(x, shape_x_), multiples, name=scope)

         try:
             out.set_shape(shape)
         except:
             pass

         return out

A = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
B = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 10])
C = tf.random_normal([20, 100, 1])

C = broadcast(C, A.shape)
D = tf.select(C, A, B)
```