# Tensorflow: broadcast gray image (mxnx1) to (mxnx3)

Tags: tensorflow, broadcast

I have a tensor and I try to stack the gray images 3-times to the depth.

```
tf.stack([mask_tensor, mask_tensor, mask_tensor], 2)
```

If I try this, there always another dimension appears...

I was already on this post: [How to explicitly broadcast a tensor to match another's shape in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362193/how-to-explicitly-broadcast-a-tensor-to-match-anothers-shape-in-tensorflow)

But they do not copy the values, just filling up with zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/tile), tiling the input tensor along the 3rd dimension 3 times:

```
tf.tile(mask_tensor, [1, 1, 3])
```